# Adding Item to cart not working codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to add item to cart, but its not adding. I am always getting message that cart is empty. Below is my code:

**controller:**

```
  $data = array(
            'id'    => $product_id,
            'qty'   => 1,
            'price' => $product_data->prod_price,
            'name'  => $product_data->prod_name,
        );
        print_r($data);

        $this->cart->insert($data);
        if (!$this->cart->contents()) {
            echo '<br/><br/>No Item in Cart';
        }
```

**Output:**
Array ( [id] => 1 [qty] => 1 [price] => 150.00 [name] => CALPOT-1L(10GM%) [Free] )

No Item in Cart

Comment: from where you are getting this output?

Comment: means what I forgot to include in my question ?

Comment: Is this from the [**deprecated** cart library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html)?

Comment: Shouldn't you check for null or empty variable instead here? `!$this->cart->contents()`. You're only checking for an empty string now.

Comment: as by CI docs: Important !

`The Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility.`. more here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/cart.html#shopping-cart-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the docs

> You have to fill 4 required fields `id,qty,price,name` if
>   they aren't filled you can't able to insert data so make sure you have
>   all four values

and then you need to check like this using `count()`:

`count($this->cart->contents())` returns the size of array.

```
if (count($this->cart->contents()) == 0)
            {
                 echo 'No Item in Cart';
        } else{
           print_r($this->cart->contents());
        }
```

Comment: print_r($this->cart->contents()); gives empty array. not getting why item is not aading in cart. M i missing anything in config file ?

Comment: as per doc you have to fill 4 required fields id,qty,price,name if they aren't filled you can't able to insert data so make sure you have all four values

Comment: Now I got the issue. When I am adding product name CALPOT-1L(10GM%) [Free] it s not adding, but when I add CALPOT as product.. its adding. may be special character issue.. if yes.. then how to solve !!

Comment: pass it by enclosing between `" "` like this `" CALPOT-1L(10GM%) [Free]"`

Answer (score 0):

Your name having special character which is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `$product_name_rules` rules in **location- project_folder/system/libraries/cart.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart {
    var $product_name_rules = '\d\D';
}
```

This will allow all characters (digits and non-digit characters) to be saved in `product_name`.